# Using chakra-ui ToolTip with a floating button

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I am attempting to create a floating "emergency exit" button for my React typescript application which will immediately take the user to weather.com. I'm having no trouble creating the button, but the requirements call for a tooltip when hovering over the button. Since we use chakra-ui throughout the product, using the Tooltip component they provide seems natural to me.

My first attempt looks like this:

Button.tsx

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button as ChakraButton, ButtonProps } from "@chakra-ui/react";

interface Props extends ButtonProps {
  buttonColor: string;
}

const Button: React.FC<Props> = ({
  buttonColor,
  children,
  ...restProps
}: Props) => (
  <ChakraButton
    backgroundColor={buttonColor}
    color="white"
    _hover={{
      background: buttonColor
    }}
    _active={{
      background: buttonColor
    }}
    padding="15px 30px"
    height="auto"
    fontSize="sm"
    minWidth="200px"
    borderRadius="100px"
    fontFamily="AvenirBold"
    {...restProps}
  >
    {children}
  </ChakraButton>
);

export default Button;
```

EmergencyExitButton.tsx

```js
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import React from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
import { Tooltip } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  z-index: 99999;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 100px);
  margin-top: 5px;
`;

export const EmergencyExitButton: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    window.open("https://weather.com", "_self");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Tooltip
        width="100%"
        label="Immediately exit to the Weather Channel. Unsaved changes will be lost."
        placement="bottom"
        bg="black"
        color="white"
      >
        <StyledButton buttonColor="#CC0000" onClick={handleClick}>
          Emergency Exit
        </StyledButton>
      </Tooltip>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};
```

When I insert this button into the application and hover over it, the tooltip appears in the top left corner of the screen and doesn't go away when you move the pointer away from the button. (codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-rain-z5szs7)

After consulting the [chakra-ui documentation on Tooltip](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/overlay/tooltip), I realized that I should be using a forwardRef for the wrapped component, so I modified EmergencyExitButton to look like this:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
import { Tooltip } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const EmergencyButton = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>((props, ref) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    window.open("https://weather.com", "_self");
  };

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      style={{
        zIndex: 99999,
        position: "fixed",
        marginLeft: "calc(75% - 100px)",
        marginTop: "5px"
      }}
    >
      <Button buttonColor="#CC0000" onClick={handleClick}>
        EmergencyExit
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
});

EmergencyButton.displayName = "EmergencyButton";

export const EmergencyExitButton: React.FC = ({ children }) => (
  <>
    <Tooltip
      width="100%"
      label="Immediately exit to the Weather Channel. Unsaved changes will be lost."
      placement="bottom"
      bg="black"
      color="white"
      hasArrow
      style={{ zIndex: 99999 }}
    >
      <EmergencyButton />
    </Tooltip>
    {children}
  </>
);
```

In this iteration, the tooltip doesn't appear at all. (codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-voice-i230ku)

I would really appreciate any advice or ideas on how to make this work.

Edited to fix the code a little.

Comment: For the record, in the forwardRef iteration, bypassing my Button component and using the chakra-ui Button instead, eliminating the div and putting the ref directly on the (chakra-ui) Button does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out that instead of creating a forwardRef, I just needed to wrap the button in a span tag.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Button from './Button';
import { Tooltip } from '@chakra-ui/react';

export const EmergencyExitButton: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    window.open('https://weather.com', '_self');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Tooltip
        width='100%'
        label='Immediately exit to the Weather Channel. Unsaved changes will be lost.'
        placement='bottom'
        bg='black'
        color='white'
      >
        <span style={{ zIndex: 99999, position: 'fixed', marginLeft: 'calc(50% - 100px)', marginTop: '5px'}}>
          <Button buttonColor='#CC0000' onClick={handleClick}>Emergency Exit</Button>
        </span>
      </Tooltip>
      {children}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: i had the same problem, and wrapping my `Image` with `span` makes the tooltip appear. but wrapping image with span seems unnatural to me. how did you figure out this would work? i want to understand the explanation. (i'm seeing the console error without span but i don't get why it is `Function components cannot be given refs.`). thank you.

Comment: btw, i found out `Tooltip` has an attribute called `shouldWrapChildren` that automatically does that for you.

Comment: @user3132457 Thanks for the tip on the `shouldWrapChildren` attribute. In my case, I needed the `span` to apply a CSS class that doesn't work properly with the button alone, so the `span` made sense. (In fact, that's how I stumbled on that as a solution to my problem.) I can see where if you didn't need that then using a `span` would feel icky; it doesn't feel great as a solution to my CSS issue either, tbh.

Answer (score 2):

I think the prop `shouldWrapChildren` could be used in this case.

See https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/tooltip/props

Comment: Since this was brought up in a relevantly older comment, you should probably refer. (I only edited to turn this from a question into an answer...) Also, please take the [tour] and read [answer].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).